# Neo4j driver throwing exception with unexpected result (.Net)

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j

I am currently trying to write a small application that simply sits on top of a `Neo4j database`, however every so often an error is being thrown in the format of:

```
Expect 4734, but got 4378
```

This doesn't consistently happen however, sometimes it just works, others it does fail but with different numbers. This happens even when using basic queries such as

```
var driver = GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://localhost", AuthTokens.Basic("neo4j", "password"));
var session = driver.Session();
var result = session.Run(MATCH (n:Movie)--() RETURN distinct (n)--()));
```

Any help would be appreciated, I've had a look at the `Neo4j.Driver` for things like timeouts along with googling it but can't seem to find anyone else encountering this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this as an anwer because i cannot comment and i want to help get an answer.

I have the same issue and have found that the issue happens when the driver is handling "too much" data if i put a limit on the query its happens less.

```
var result = session.Run("match (t:Term {value:'"+search.Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace(@"'", @"\'") + "'})-[:IsIn]->(d:Document) return d.url as url limit 75");
```

Limited to 75 it only does it in rare cases, 90 it does it pretty randomly and at a 100 it does it more often than not.

I am using Neo4j in as database to a rest service.
It also does it if i send many request at the same time.

Folowing is what the Neo4J server prints in the debug log:

```
2016-05-25 19:27:44.111+0000 ERROR [o.n.b.t.SocketTransportHandler] Fatal
error occurred when handling a client connection: An existing connection was 
forcibly closed by the remote host An existing connection was forcibly closed by 
the remote host
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I hope the extra info helps solve this -Niels